# is there an escape for '&' character in the command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I am trying something like:

```
set pwd = abc&123
echo password %pwd%
```

I get the result as...

```
'123' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 
password abc
```

Is the system like this or is there an escape for such characters?

Comment: The same question in SO [How do I escape ampersands in batch files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1327431)

Answer (score 12):

What you need to do is wrap your password in double quotes like so:

```
set pwd="abc&123"
echo %pwd%
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Another option which may be preferable in some scenarios is `set "pwd=abc&123"`

Comment: -1 it is shocking that this has had 5 upvotes, it's wrong. Windows uses %var% or !var!  you could've tested it yourself so easily. $var  is in linux, if you echo $var in windows it just says literally $var

Comment: @barlop: seeing as it's the *other* line that addresses the question, I don't see that it matters.

Answer (score 10):

I found that it works best with a combination of both martineau's answer and mastashake57's answer.

```
set pwd=abc^&123
echo %pwd%
```

Still fails, and

```
set pwd="abc&123"
echo %pwd%
```

Adds quotes to it (you can't remove the quotes with a `for` loop or string manipultaion because it will fail again, thanks to the ampersand), which isn't that great.

However,

```
set "pwd=abc^&123"
echo %pwd%
```

Works perfectly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1.  Be aware that this leaves the carat in the environment variable, i.e., it sets `pwd` to `abc^&123`.  Most of the time this is probably exactly what you need to do, but it could catch you out if you're not aware of what's happening.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I must correct your spelling error. It's carEt. btw I know ntcmds.chm mentions it, but where in cmd /? documentation is it mentioned about the caret being the escape character?

Comment: @Barlop: so it is; I was confusing it with the homonym.  As a general rule `/?` only provides a summary, not comprehensive documentation.

Comment: @barlop, ? The caret is the escape character.

Comment: @Pacerier yes, caret is the escape character ,  nobody is disagreeing with that.  and it is mentioned that it is the escape character, in ntcmds.chm(ntcmds.chm came with XP and is in an equivalent online http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_o.mspx?mfr=true   and maybe in some ways more up to date online - maybe more commands).   I was just asking where in /? (if anywhere), it says that caret is the escape character

Comment: and I know you know this but i'll add, that when we say escape character, we don't mean ascii 27  (unless perhaps a program tried to use that character as the escape character! - prompt might've come done it in a sense or close $e[ , or perhaps not)

Answer (score 7):

From the command-line reference help file:

> The ampersand (&), pipe (|), and parentheses ( ) are special
>   characters that must be preceded by the escape character (^) or
>   quotation marks when you pass them as arguments.

Seems like putting the whole password in quotation marks would be easier than escaping individual characters if there's more than two characters within it that need the treatment.

Comment: And quotes within quotes?

Answer (score 5):

What you really need is:

```
set pwd=abc^^^&123
echo %pwd%
```

Or:

```
set "pwd=abc^&123"
echo %pwd%
```

#### Explanation:

Since `&` is a special char, you must escape it with `^`, resulting in `^&`.

Running `set pwd=abc^&123` will set the variable to the value `abc&123`. After that, if you were to run `echo %pwd%`, you are effectively running `echo abc&123`.

Yet `echo abc&123` doesn't work as you expect, because `&` is a special char. You can avoid this by adding quotes: `echo "abc&123"` but your output would have the quote chars too. In other words, using quotes isn't exactly a proper solution.

What you need is to escape the `&` char when you run the `echo` command:

```
echo abc^&123
```

So the variable needs to contain the value `abc^&123`. To set the variable to the value `abc^&123`, you would need to escape the special chars `^` and `&`, resulting in:

```
set pwd=abc^^^&123
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the need to escape the caret

Comment: Works great, thank you. This escape character is not mentioned in the doc in some reason https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd

Answer (score 0):

I needed a solution for cases where the location of the & character is unknown, this seems to work for me:

```
set "pwd=abc&123"
set "EchoablePassword=%pwd:&=^&%"
echo password %EchoablePassword%
```

Not all commands requires the escape of the & character!!!
For example the "if exist" command won't work if you escape the & character, but will work if you don't escape it. This is why I named the variable as "EchoablePassword" because in my code only echo requires the escape of "&".